# Worst Case Time Complexity of this Quicksort algoritmn

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This quicksort algorithm selects its pivot by randomly selecting 2√n elements in the list and finding the median using insertion sort.(O(n) time) In the worst case it selects an element smaller or larger than n-√n elements, and so on. How do you determine the running time?